# Installing Single EXE Applications

Tags: installer

Often times I find a tool or utility on the internet such as [SnippetCompiler](http://www.sliver.com/dotnet/SnippetCompiler/) that is very useful. However, many of these types of tools aren't packaged with an installer. I was wondering if there is any quick tool to generate an installer from a single EXE? I am a developer and know about WIX, InstallShield, and adding shortcuts to Program Files and start menu. I am just wondering if there are any quick tools to accomplish the same thing as simply as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a program that will create, from a single program.exe a self-installing package that another person can use to install program.exe on their Windows computer and which will then show up in the control-panel remove-applications list with an uninstall optiion.

The simplest I have found is probably [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php). Like several such programs, you write a small text file to tell it what is to be included. Heres an example from an online [tutorial](http://johnnycoder.com/blog/2008/07/28/getting-started-with-inno-setup/)

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVerName=My Program version 1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program
DefaultGroupName=My Program
UninstallDisplayIcon={app}\MyProg.exe
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes
OutputDir=userdocs:Inno Setup Examples Output

[Files]
Source: “MyProg.exe”; DestDir: “{app}”

[Icons]
Name: “{group}\My Program”; Filename: “{app}\MyProg.exe”
```

So you write that file, run Inno Setup and it produces a file that others can download and run to install program.exe on their Windows computer.

Answer (score 2):

While it's designed for stuff packed into .zip files rather than standalone .exes, [NirSoft's ZipInstaller](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/zipinst.html) would be right up your alley.  It's designed to extract .zip files and install their contents, putting files in the `Program Files` folder, creating links in the `Start Menu`, and so on.